# SpringBoot: JWT Error (Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I've been following this tutorial to create a YouTube Clone using Angular+SpringBoot:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW1nQ4o3sCI&t=15427s

What i'm trying to do right is now is to create a user registration endpoint using OAuth, so i can write the user information on my database. However, i'm having some issues with JWT.

Whenever i try to access the endpoint (localhost:8080/api/user/register) i do receive the following error on my console:

> [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to
> authenticate since the JWT was invalid

Setting some breakpoints and debuggging the application, on SecurityConfig.java the JWT is okay (it returns a valid object). However, when trying to call the endpoint using postman and sending my token as a Bearer token, i do receive the error i sent above.
And i can't even debug the UserController ; even setting the breakpoints, when i call the endpoint   i don't know what happens but i just receive the error. The only way i can debug trough the controller is if i call using my browse. But when doing so, the authentication is null so it won't work.

UserController.java

```
package com.pablo.portfolio.youtubeclone.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {


    private final UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/register")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String register(Authentication authentication){

        Jwt jwt = (Jwt)authentication.getPrincipal();
        userRegistrationService.registerUser(jwt.getTokenValue());
        return "User registered successfully";
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.pablo.portfolio.youtubeclone.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer.uri}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable().authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/videos/","/save-video-details/","/upload-video/","/thumbnail/").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/api/private-scoped").hasAuthority("SCOPE_read:messages")
                .and().cors()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();



    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

Also, i checked the token o jwt.io and its valid.
Here's the response:

```
Header:
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "7_mQttmzor-VMdGDXMEKN"
}

Payload:
{
  "iss": "https://dev-i63rcznjs255jxgf.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "google-oauth2|113855475209558231767",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "https://dev-i63rcznjs255jxgf.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1681740331,
  "exp": 1681826731,
  "azp": "NJbox1ptzDdadd1Zo9mlBvtkElgge59v",
  "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

EDIT: FUll log

```
2023-04-19T22:07:32.963-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [           main] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {securityConfig=com.pablo.portfolio.youtubeclone.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0@61d2f267}
2023-04-19T22:07:32.964-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
2023-04-19T22:07:34.768-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Mvc [pattern='/']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.780-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Mvc [pattern='/api/videos/']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.780-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Mvc [pattern='/save-video-details/']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.780-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Mvc [pattern='/upload-video/']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.780-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Mvc [pattern='/thumbnail/']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.780-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [hasAuthority('SCOPE_read:messages')] for Mvc [pattern='/api/private-scoped']
2023-04-19T22:07:34.788-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2023-04-19T22:07:34.789-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2023-04-19T22:07:34.794-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@ecf028c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7b64bbad, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@68f2363, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@d978ab9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@71eff6a3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@484302ee, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@4cd8db31, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@86377d5, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@87220f1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@574218f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@d180961, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@35d114f4]
2023-04-19T22:07:34.963-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-04-19T22:07:34.972-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [           main] c.p.p.y.YoutubeCloneApplication          : Started YoutubeCloneApplication in 5.035 seconds (process running for 5.444)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.036-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-19T22:07:56.036-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-19T22:07:56.038-03:00  INFO 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-04-19T22:07:56.043-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@ecf028c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7b64bbad, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@68f2363, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@d978ab9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@71eff6a3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@484302ee, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@4cd8db31, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@86377d5, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@87220f1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@574218f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@d180961, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@35d114f4]] (1/1)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.044-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/user/register
2023-04-19T22:07:56.045-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.045-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.047-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.048-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.050-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.053-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.053-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-04-19T22:07:56.053-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.055-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
2023-04-19T22:07:56.068-03:00 DEBUG 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2023-04-19T22:07:56.070-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException: Unable to validate Jwt
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:100) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidationException: Unable to validate Jwt
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.validateJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:189) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:96) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 58 common frames omitted

2023-04-19T22:07:56.075-03:00 TRACE 1909589 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

Comment: @JohnWilliams that linked tutorial contains bad practices and is not the way the handling of JWTs should be handled. Writing a custom JWT filter is a bad practice that we do not recommend. Spring security already has built in handling for JWTs so please do not link that tutorial. Here is the docs for implementing jwt handling in spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html

Comment: Please enable debug logs and post your full logs, only an exception tells us nothing. Also see this example https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: EDIT: Added the full debug log.

Comment: Could you please change the lvl to TRACE and update the logs

Comment: Changed debug level. Had to remove initial part of it to fit the character limit. Also now that i'm seeing other erros i'm analyzing them also.

Comment: the token seems expired at `2023-04-18T22:41:29Z` while the logs printing is saying the time is `2023-04-19T14:11:58.310-03:00`

Comment: There's no problem with token expiration. Just out of curiosity i've cleared the session storage and issued a new token. Compared the end of the tokens, they were different. Still the same thing. I've updated the log with the results i got right now.

Comment: Toerktumlare i used the github repo you sent and made a few changes. With those changes the error now is "Couldn't parse remote JWK set: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $". At least it changed :D

Comment: That means that what you are getting from your JWK endpoint is not correctly formatted JSON, check what the url returns

Comment: The URLS i have are the issuer URI, userInfo endpoint and the auth0_uri/.well-known/openid-configuration . Inside this one i do have "../.well-known/jwks.json", where i received a well formed json. I'm currently trying to access localhost:8080/api/user/register using postman and passing the bearer token i got from logging in on the frontend (copying from session storage inside chrome inspect).

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing your explanation is not very clear. The error message clearly states that it could not parse the data that its getting from the JWK endpoint it expected an `OBJECT` which in `JSON` is represented by an opening bracket `{` but it received a `STRING` instead, so some form of text, and `JSON` is only allowed to start with either a curly bracket or a hard bracket. Step debug your application, see what you are getting.

Comment: Yeah I got that part. However using postman I do only post the bearer token and I don’t know how it deals with it. I tried adding some brackets(forcing a json format) but it didn’t worked as well.  The repo with this project is: https://github.com/paboobhzx/youtube-clone . There’s nothing fancy, I’ll try a few things later but I got that part (I read the error message :D )

Comment: i cant help you more, since you are using auth0 and i dont have time to set up all that and try to debug. You need to debug the creation of the JWTDecoder, so set a breakpoint at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e57e8b3722e796724a4b5ebcce16b165c869fcdf/oauth2/oauth2-jose/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoders.java#L112 and then you should end up here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e57e8b3722e796724a4b5ebcce16b165c869fcdf/oauth2/oauth2-jose/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoders.java#L112

Comment: and ensure that the jwk url is ccorrectc and that the data you get from that endpoint is correct. Stacck overflow is not a forum, and these comments have dragged things out quite long now

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there is a typo here

```java
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer.uri}")
```

Should be

```java
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update SecurityConfig.java :

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> 
    authorize.antMatchers("/api/videos/","/save-video-details/","/upload- 
    video/","/thumbnail/")
   .permitAll()
   .anyRequest()
   .authenticated())
   .sessionManagement()
   .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
   .and()
   .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
   .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
    oauth2ResourceServer
   .jwt(jwt ->
     jwt.decoder(JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer)))
 );
return http.build();
}
see this reference : https://curity.io/resources/learn/oidc-spring-boot/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).